# How to use composer on windows?

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php

I have installed xampp on my PC. After that I installed composer using window installer. On the website they tell about composer.json which looks something like this in the example

```
{
"require": {
    "monolog/monolog": "1.2.*"
}
}
```

Where do I put it? How do I run it? I have searched a lot but found nothing. Any suggestion would be great.

I ran command prompt as administrator with following command

```
C:\windows\system32>composer
```

It printed out a bunch of commands. I tried typing

```
C:\windows\system32>composer install
```

I got an error that composer could not find composer.json file

Comment: Hit the Windows button on your keyboard, type "cmd" and hit Enter. Then type "composer" and hit Enter. What happens?

Comment: It shows a list of commands. I am updating the answer to include what else I got.

Comment: Okay. You should put the `composer.json` file in your website's root directory. Then, in your terminal, go to the folder where you put the file (e.g. `cd C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite`) and then type `composer install`. That should be it.

Comment: Please wait let me check and get back to you.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Okay, let's say your website is at:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\
```

You should put the Composer file at:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\composer.json
```

Then, in your terminal, use these two commands:

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite
composer install
```

That should be it.

You can do various other things with Composer. To find out what type `composer` in your terminal. It will show you a list of commands you can use.

If you want to know more about a command then you can use `composer help [COMMAND]`, like so:

```
composer help install
```

Comment: Thank you. I now have two folders inside folder vendor named composer and monolog. There is also a file autoload.php. I think this means that everything worked.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I've just installed composer. And i'm trying to use the html2pdf package. I've installed it using composer but i'm not sure how to use it in my php code. I'm using single file to test the package, but not sure how to import and use it. Can you help?

Comment: @FreeKrishna Have you used the search box (top right of the page)? If you have, and not found anything, then you should create a new question :)

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen  The problem was i didn't knew how to use the autoload.php file once the composer loads the packages. But i did figure it out. Thanks for the response. :)