# PHPMailer v6 Get Started

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am the beginner of PHPMailer therefore I would like to know which file do i want to include from PHPMailer folder.

Simple Code:

```
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

There is `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;`, `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;`, `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` lines. But there are no folder call vendor and no autoload.php file anywhere in PHPMailer folder.

According to website they said [LINK](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

> At the very least you will need src/PHPMailer.php. If you're using
> SMTP, you'll need src/SMTP.php, and if you're using POP-before SMTP,
> you'll need src/POP3.php.

Therefore I removed use tow lines and I added three require lines which are PHPMailer.php, SMTP.php and Exception.php. But it is also not working.

How to get start with this PHPMailer.

Comment: Should be used with composer, see https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading - PHPMailer is available on Packagist (using semantic versioning), and installation via composer is the recommended way to install PHPMailer

Comment: Yeah, but there are no autoload.php

Comment: It will be once you run `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer`

Answer (score 2):

You have to install composer through this
[link](https://getcomposer.org/download/), Click on Composer-setup.exe and run it.
After installing you will get json files cut/copy the file and paste it in your root directory, and then go to command prompt and write this line.

> composer install

When it get finished you will get vendor folder and inside it there will be autoload.php,
Copy the file and paste it to the directory or folder where your send-mail file is.
If you want more example click on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441950/how-to-use-composer-on-windows)
More Information about composer read this [Page](https://github.com/composer/composer)